# Zbar not scanning after use of camera

Tags: zbar-sdk, zbar

I have an app that start with scanning a qr code.

After scanning if I use the camera to take picture and then go back to the
scanning view the scanning does not work.

I dont know the reason, issue is only in IOS7 devices, both iPad and iPhone.

I tried to setSymbology and called `[readerView start]`, but it didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that IOS7 change the video mode for AVCaptureSession after you take a photo. Use this code **before** you call `[readerView start]`.

```
if([readerView.session canSetSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])
    readerView.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
```